# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘[Char]’

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, monads, io-monad

```
myTakeWhile :: (a-> Bool ) -> [a] -> [a]
myTakeWhile _ [] = []
myTakeWhile pred (head:tail) = if pred head
                           then head:myTakeWhile pred tail
                           else []

main =  myTakeWhile (/= ' ') "This is practice."
```

gives me this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘IO t0’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
```

Answer (score 4):

A `main` always has type `IO something`, not a `String` which is the result type `myTakeWhile (/= ' ') "This is practice."`.

You can work with [**`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) to print it as a string *literal*, or [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) to print the *content* of the string, so:

```
main :: IO ()
main =  print (myTakeWhile (/= ' ') "This is practice.")
```